# Windows startup - how to run a program as administrator from a batch file

Tags: windows-8.1, uac

On Windows 8.1, I am trying to start a program from a batch file which is called during startup and I want the program to run as Administrator.
Here is what I do:

1. I have a program prog.exe under c:\program files\MyProgram
2. The EXE is flagged to "Run as Administrator"
3. Under c:\program files\MyProgram there is a batch file called RunEXE.bat. It contains all sorts of things and the end it contains a line "start prog.exe"
4. under "C:\programdata\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp" there is a shortcut to RunEXE.BAT.
5. When I reboot the PC I expect the shortcut to launch the RunEXE.BAT which in turn will run PROG.EXE.

But it does not happen. There is a short "bleep" sound as if Windows is displaying a message asking to confirm the program should run as Administrator but nothing is visible on the screen.

a) If I flag the shortcut & exe **NOT** to run as admin, then the EXE is launched.
b) If I flag the shortcut & exe **to run** as admin, then the EXE is **not** launched.
c) If I flag the shortcut to **NOT** to run as admin and the EXE **to run** as admin then the EXE **is launched** but it **does not run as administrator**.
d) Startup shortcut to the EXE. (No batch). Shortcut **not** flagged to run as administrator, EXE **is** flagged: EXE not running.
e) Startup shortcut to the EXE. (No batch). Shortcut **not** flagged to run as administrator, EXE **not** flagged: EXE is running but not as administrator.

I tried disabling the UAC completely - same results.
I also tried to have another EXE instead of the batch, with the same results.

So - is there a way to have a shortcut to an EXE from startup which will run an EXE as administrator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with help of the Task Scheduler.

Open Run dialog `Win + R` and run following command:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\taskschd.msc
```

Hit `Create Task...`

1. Set name (i set it FooBar)
2. Check `Run with highest privileges`
3. Switch to `Actions` tab, `New....`, browse to your **prog.exe**
4. Save task

Go to your **.bat** file and at the place where you want to run your **prog.exe** add

```
schtasks /run /tn "FooBar"
```

Bat file doesn't have to run as administrator (if it doesn't need to), prog.exe will start elevated without any prompts.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to elevate a batch script, as long as you have powershell on your computer:

```
net file 1>nul 2>nul && goto :run || powershell -ex unrestricted -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%comspec%' -ArgumentList '/c %~fnx0 %*'"
```